# Trying to make a slideshow with jQuery but can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Hi i am trying to make a slideshow for my webpage but i can't make it work. It is my first time using jQuery and im not so good at js either. Can someone see what i have done wrong?
Here are my html, css and js codes.

HTML

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="matsidacss.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jul.js"></script>
    <title>Erik'p kokbok</title>
</head>
<body class="jul" onload="slider();">   
      <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="Bilder/food1.jpg" border="0" alt="food1"></img>
        <img id="2" src="Bilder/food2.jpg" border="0" alt="food2"></img>
        <img id="3" src="Bilder/food3.jpg" border="0" alt="food3"></img>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
    .slider
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 205px;
    width: 230px;
    left: 50%;
    top:10px;
    margin-left:510px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.slider img
{
    width:230px;
    height:205px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#1').show("fade",2000);
    $('#2').delay(500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);
    var sc=$(".slider img").size();
    var count=2;

    setInterval(function(){
    $("#1"+count).show("slide", {direction:"right"}, 500);
    $("#2"+count).delay(500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);
    if(count == sc){
        count=1;
    }else{
        count=count+1;
    }
    }, 6500);
})
```

Thanks for helping//Anton

Comment: The body tag says there is a "slider" function running when the page is loaded. What's that function?

Comment: The function is in the javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

I explain you, I would change all the images' css but the first with display:none because '.hide' and '.show' changes the display, so you can't show something that is already showed.

So I will give you an example [here JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5wm7/) of how a Slider could work:

HTML

```
    <div id="slider">
    <img src="http://avatar.hq-picture.com/avatars/img27/say_cheese_avatar_picture_52454.jpg" id="image1"></img>
    <img src="http://www.animated-gifs.eu/avatars-100x100-dogs/0038.gif" id="image2"></img>
    <img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs39/f/2008/330/0/2/Lfg_avatar_100x100_by_Shadowfang3000.gif" id="image3"></img>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#image1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Javascript

```
var cont = 1;

setInterval(function () { //Make an action repeat each 1000 ms
    $("#image" + cont).hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500); //Go out
    if (cont == 3) { //To repeat the complete cycle
        cont = 1;
    } else {
        cont++;
    }
    $("#image" + cont).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);  //Go in
}, 1000); //The 1000 ms
```

It is very commented and I think that it should be useful for you.
There is another way to do it, selecting all image elements or all the elements with the class "imageSlider", but it is way more complicated to understand compared with the way that I have showed you. 
I hope it will useful to you.

Patch

PS: try to don't name your id with just a numbers.

PS2: the images aren't mine, I took it from google images.

Answer (score 0):

Anton,

Not sure what your requirements are for the slideshow, but maybe you could use Twitter Bootstrap's slideshow.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

It's effortless to get it up. Hope this helps.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Ive put together a jsfiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/XexmW/

There are a few issues with your markup/css/js.

- img tags dont need to have a close tag - im not sure it will be understood by all browsers. Use `<img src="" />` instead.
- you still have an onload function call in your html
- `"#1"+count` wont sum 1 and count, then append it to #. if `count = 1` then it would give you `'#11'`
- when i was playing around, i could only get the images to butt up against each other nicely if they have position:absolute

Here are my alterations:

**html**

```
  <div class="slider">
      <img id="1" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02422/burger_2422297b.jpg" border="0" alt="food1" />
      <img id="2" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02443/shoppingbasket_2443279b.jpg" border="0" alt="food2" />
      <img id="3" src="http://o-food.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/O-food-photos-overview-161.jpg" border="0" alt="food3" />
  </div>
```

**css**

```
    .slider
{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.slider img
{
    position:absolute;
    width:230px;
    height:205px;
    display:none;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('#1').show();

    var sc=$(".slider img").size();

    var count=1;
    var lastCount = 0;

    setInterval(function(){

        lastCount = count;

        if(count == sc){
            count=1;
        }else{
            count++;
        }        

        $("#"+count).show("slide", {direction:"right"}, 500);
        $("#"+lastCount).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    }, 1000);
})
```

Having said all that - if you can use an existing library or jQuery plugin, its likely to be more stable and x-browser compatible.